# Show that $(p \land q) \to (p \lor q)\equiv(p \lor ¬p) \land (q \lor \neg q)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm stuck while trying to show that $(p \land q) \to (p \lor q)$ is logically equivalent to $(p \lor ¬p) \land (q \lor \neg q)$. I know they're equivalent (they're tautologies) because they both have the same truth table but I'm not sure how to start from $(p \land q) \to (p \lor q)$ and finally get $(p \lor ¬p) \land (q \lor \neg q)$.

What I have done so far is this:

\begin{align*}
(p \land q) \to (p \lor q)&\equiv\neg(p \land q) \lor (p \lor q)&\text{(Definition of $\to$)}\\
&\equiv(\neg p\lor\neg q)\lor (p \lor q)&\text{(De Morgan's Law)}\\
&\equiv(\neg p\lor\neg p)\lor (q \lor q)&\text{(Associativity and commutativity of $\lor$)}\\
\end{align*}

I don't see how to get a conjunction from there. I know I could say both disjunctions on my last step are $\mathrm{TRUE} \lor \mathrm{TRUE} \equiv \mathrm{TRUE}$ but I don't think it will leave me to get the conjunction I'm looking for, right?

I appreacite your help.

Comment: What rules of inference/replacement are you allowed to use in your proof?

Comment: @AlannRosas Only basic equivalences. Here you can check them: https://postimg.cc/Z9n9565t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to math.SE!!

Since $p\lor\neg p\equiv\mathrm{T}$ and $q\lor\neg q\equiv\mathrm{T}$, you have
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{T}\lor\mathrm{T}&\equiv\mathrm{T}\\
&\equiv\mathrm{T}\land \mathrm{T}\\
&\equiv(p\lor\neg p)\land(q\lor\neg q).
\end{align*}